# variable resetting "randomly"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am building a text based adventure game and I'm currently stuck on an issue.

I have a two variables that hold the values for the `map(rooms)` called `x` and `y`, I am changing them from a class and as soon as it exits the class code back to main it resets the values for `x` and `y`.

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
...
void IncreaseY(){
    y++;
}
void MoveDirection(Direction direction)
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
        case North:
            DecreaseY();
            break;
        case South:
            IncreaseY();
            break;
        case East:
            IncreaseX();
            break;
        case West:
            DecreaseX();
            break;
        case None:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
...
class player{
    void DoStuff()
    {
    MoveDirection(South);
    }
}
...
void main()
{
    Player player = Player.NewOrLoadCharacter();
    player.doStuff();
}
```

This is most of the relevant code summarized.

I have stepped through the program using breakpoints and stepping several times and I am completely sure that as soon as I leave the Player class the variables `x` and `y` reset back to `0`.

### Question:

What could be causing the resetting of the variables `x` and `y`?

Note: This is an issue that just popped up since it has worked previously just fine.

edit: Source code: http://pastebin.com/uKS55LEZ

P.S.: I know the code is poorly written, I started with C++ moving from C# a week ago.

Comment: You know that you have a debugger at hand, do you?

Comment: The problem is underneath the code written as "...". I'm curious as to why you thought you knew which bits of code would be relevant when you don't know what the problem is? lol

Comment: When simplifying make sure 1. the simplification compiles and 2. the simplification duplicates the error. After stripping out all the stuff that can't compile and fixing the bits that don't, I am unable to reproduce.

Comment: are `x` and `y` global variables?

Comment: Where are the `x` and `y` defined?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/uKS55LEZ

Here's the source code if somebody wants to poke around

Comment: It should be clear by now that there isn't sufficient code in the example to reproduce the problem. I surmise the x and y you're referencing a members of an object, but in the debugger you also have another x and y, perhaps global values, which happen to have the same name. In various contexts that might look to you like they're changing, when in reality you're seeing these values from different scopes.

Comment: pro-tip: `void main` is bogus.

Comment: @StefanJonsson A link to an external website with nearly 900 loc is not particularly useful either. Please provide a [mcve] *in the question itself*.

Comment: The "simplified" version was meant to be taken as pseudo code, sorry. I was basically wondering if anyone else has ever experienced a similar issue before and if so could help me fix it. The code that I use has worked before, I have only moved around where I call the function from, nothing else and now it does no longer work.

Comment: Unrelated recommendation: Rather than having enums defining wizard, warrior, etc, and all of the switch/cases that result, consider a class hierarchy: `class Character`, `class Wizard: public Character`, `class WizardTank: public Wizard` and let polymorphism do the heavy lifting.

Comment: You can avoid problems like this by making your class uncopyable if it never makes sense to copy it.

Comment: Good point David Schwartz; that would have revealed the underlying problem which emerged in version 2 of the OP's externally posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code changed considerably since this answer was first posted, yet the problem is still actually a kind of mirage.

Here's what's happening at the current version of the code (the OP question does not represent this situation at the time of this writing):

In main, there is a Player declared thus:

```
Player player;
```

In a standard game loop, this code exists:

```
while( true )
 { 
   ClearConsole();
   Print(map.CreateMap(player));
   map.doRoom(player);
 }
```

This is greatly improved over earlier versions (much cleaner). There is one small problem causing the behavior described. It's the signature of the function doRoom (and this may apply to CreateMap, though I doubt it).

```
void doRoom(Player player)
```

This is a member of Room (in the loop above, that's map). The problem is that player is passed by value. This means a copy of player is made to provide the input parameter for doRoom. This copy is changed by doRoom (moving x and y, for example). When doRoom returns, the copy which it acts upon evaporates (falls from scope) - and the edited data goes with it.

Change the signature to

```
void doRoom(Player & player)
```

Now, the function takes a reference to player. There is no copy being made. As such, changes made to player are retained from one iteration of the loop to the next.

I said earlier this MIGHT apply to map.CreateMap, but that's true only if CreateMap modifies contents of player. If not, it wouldn't matter, but it would be technically slower to create a copy of player just to make the output CreateMap produces. It can take a reference, as I've suggested doRoom must take.

There is one other minor problem. The main loop above has no means of escape. There is no way to end the game. `map.doRoom( player )` should probably return a bool, and perhaps if a false is returned, break the loop.

Comment: I did as you suggested and the results are the same, the thing is that when I'm following the debugger it's increasing the x and y from the top of the program, but as soon as it returns to main because it's done with the current room, it resets the value of x and y back to 0.

Comment: At present, with your posted code (the long version that compiled), I can't fathom how to leave the current room to even test that.

Comment: Try the exact opposite for a revealing experiment. Change the global x and y to pos_x and pos_y, which reveals where you have FREQUENTLY used x and y in confusing contexts between global and local scope. Compile, fix (it's a process, takes 2 minutes here)...should be good then. The problem is still as stated, just....you have several places where you use x and y without context being clear. This illustrates why global variables are highly discouraged. In this case, it seems to me, that pos_x and pos_y (as I've proposed you use) are actually the player's position, and belong in that object.

Comment: I'm sorry it's very early development and not meant to be tested by other players, the code that's used to move from the first room would be "Move South" but that's the thing, after that's executed Y gets increased and you move to room[0][1], but then as soon as it goes back to main it resets y to 0, so you're stuck in the same room forever.

Yes they are the players positions I just havn't moved them into the player class as of yet, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Then try the change to pos_x and pos_y first. You have confusion going on because of that (specifically, between global scope and local scope within functions). After that, consider design points, like putting position into the player instead of a global value. That way you can have multiple players

Comment: I have cleaned up the code a bit and updated the same pastebin, I still have issues even though I have moved everything relevant to position into player. could you take a quick look through and see if you can solve the issue I have?

Comment: Ok, I've changed the answer to fit the current state of your program. The code is better now, what's left is a very minor problem described above in the answer.

Comment: BTW, I congratulate you on finding a completely different method of introducing the same looking bug ;). That would be quite a mystery.